# Not Understanding Why Adding IN causes huge performance hit with SqlServer 2014

Tags: sql-server

I'm having trouble understanding how adding just adding the top select causes the query to go from taking 48 ms to 7000 ms.  Basically, if I execute just the query highlighted in yellow, it takes 48 ms.  When I add the top part it takes 7000 ms.  The total number of rows returned is only 60 so I can't understand why the slow down.  It feels as if it's executing all rows in my attendees files, not just the 60 that are found in the in clause.

Query:

[image: Full Query Including In Clause]

[image: Plan for full query above]

[image: Plan for just part in yellow]

Full Query Including In Clause
Plan for full query above
Plan for just part in yellow
Raw Query:

```
SELECT Attendees.Id,
       Attendees.UserFirstName,
       Attendees.UserLastName,
       Attendees.Email
FROM Attendees
WHERE Id IN (
              SELECT DISTINCT dbo.Attendees.Id
              FROM dbo.SessionAttendee
                   INNER JOIN dbo.Attendees ON (
                     dbo.SessionAttendee.Attendees_username = dbo.Attendees.PKID
                     )
                   INNER JOIN dbo.Sessions ON (dbo.SessionAttendee.Sessions_id =
                     dbo.Sessions.Id)
              WHERE dbo.Sessions.CodeCampYearId = 104 AND
                    dbo.SessionAttendee.Interestlevel = 3
      )
```

Comment: Dunno.  You could rewrite that as a join instead, might help perf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you need top query, can't you just select everything from the first query?

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
   Attendees.Id,
   Attendees.UserFirstName,
   Attendees.UserLastName,
   Attendees.Email
 FROM dbo.SessionAttendee
 INNER JOIN dbo.Attendees ON (
                 dbo.SessionAttendee.Attendees_username = dbo.Attendees.PKID
                 )
 INNER JOIN dbo.Sessions ON (dbo.SessionAttendee.Sessions_id =
                 dbo.Sessions.Id)
 WHERE dbo.Sessions.CodeCampYearId = 104 AND
                dbo.SessionAttendee.Interestlevel = 3
```

Comment: Yes, if `Attendees.Id` is the primary key, it will be unique anyway and additional columns won't change the behavior of DISTINCT.

Comment: this improved the perf to what the inner query did (of course).  The only reason I separated it is because I have a lot of queries that just return a single value (attendees.Id) that then I put into an IN clause.  Most of my queries I use this for are machine generated so the in clause makes life easier.

Answer (score 0):

You could try EXISTS instead.

```
SELECT  a.Id,
        a.UserFirstName,
        a.UserLastName,
        a.Email
FROM    Attendees a
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT  1 
    FROM    dbo.Sessions s
            JOIN SessionAttendee sa ON sa.Sessions_id = s.Id 
    WHERE   s.CodeCampYearId = 104
            AND sa.Interestlevel = 3
            AND sa.Attendees_username = a.PKID
)
```

The `IN` part might not be affecting performance as much as the `DISTINCT` part is

Comment: Thanks @JamieD77  I tried removing the distinct and it did not change the perf. I'm still confused why it is so much slower.